# Floating objects from model after applying 'with automatic weights' I need help.

Tags: rigging, rigify, error

[image]

I'm having a rigify error after applying 'with automatic weights'. My character's hair is floating after I move around the rig and it's frustrating that I have no idea how to fix it. I don't know how to manually weight paint either. (I'm a big noob)

Comment: Answer provided, there are couple of things that may solve it. You can upload your .blend file on blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select your mesh and Switch to Weight Painting mode using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Select your armature and switch to Pose mode using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Rotate your head bone as shown in the figure you posted, which will leave the other parts of the head not moved.
- Now select your head bone and start weight painting using Mouse left click as shown below until all these parts are red, where these parts of the head will be assigned to the bone head and will move with it. You may need to turn off the limit selection as highlighted below

[image]

Comment: I just got this showing up. Thank you so much. So it didn't apply anything to it at all. Not only that. You taught me how to clean up weight painting. Thank You!!  http://imgur.com/50UjcoT

Comment: @CodyMavar You are welcome, glad I helped. you can accept the answer  if it solved your problem :)